# Using variables in AngularJS tags

Tags: angularjs

To create URL links for a list using ng-repeat, how should I use variables in location.href?

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success me-1" onclick="location.href='/view-panel/{{ item.url}}'"> no: {{item.no}}

</button>

</ul>
```

I tried, but it's not working. Please let me know a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-click` like this

HTML

```
<button type="button" 
  class="btn btn-success me-1" 
  ng-click="navigateToPanel(item.url)">
```

code

```
$scope.navigateToPanel = function(itemUrl) { 
  location.href =`/view-panel/${ itemUrl }`;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it inside a `a` tag with an `ng-href` defined and it should work!

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items">
    <a ng-href="/view-panel/{{item.url}}">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success me-1"> no: {{item.no}}</button>
    </a>
</ul>
```